# Write a list into csv in python

Tags: python

I want to write a list into a csv file in python. This is a subset of my input list.

```
rows= ([u'Feng Ming', u'Cao', u'China Samsung Telecom', u'Beijing', u'', u'CHINA'], 
    [u'Naftali', u'Chayat', u'Alvarion Ltd.', u'Tel Aviv', u'', u'ISRAEL'],
    [u'R\xe9mi', u'Chayer', u'Harris Corporation', u'Dollard-Des-Ormeaux', u'PQ', u'CANADA'])
```

However, when I am using the code

```
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Its showing error because of the character "R\xe9mi". Any lead to solve this problem will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `import unicodecsv as csv` to do this task.

```
import unicodecsv as csv
rows= [u'Feng Ming', u'Cao', u'China Samsung Telecom', u'Beijing', u'', u'CHINA'], [u'Naftali', u'Chayat', u'Alvarion Ltd.', u'Tel Aviv', u'', u'ISRAEL'], [u'R\xe9mi', u'Chayer', u'Harris Corporation', u'Dollard-Des-Ormeaux', u'PQ', u'CANADA']

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

**output.csv :**

```
Feng Ming,Cao,China Samsung Telecom,Beijing,,CHINA
Naftali,Chayat,Alvarion Ltd.,Tel Aviv,,ISRAEL
Rémi,Chayer,Harris Corporation,Dollard-Des-Ormeaux,PQ,CANADA
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `unicodecsv`

`pip install unicodecsv`

```
import unicodecsv as csv
# Your code
```